# ListView item selection and exception handling

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listView of items, in which the user can only select one at a time. I have the following code, that only works properly when I put it in a try/catch block. The problem is, that some of the item names are too long, and they cause a lot of white space for the other items. Clicking on the white space will cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, even though it is in the same row as an item. I solved this by shoving it in a try/catch block, but I feel this is a dirty way of doing it, even if it works. Below is the code.

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] arr1 = File.ReadAllLines(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString());
        string[] arr2 = arr1[0].Split(';');
    }
    catch
    {
        //no catch
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid this altogether, but I do not know how to change the code to make it work without the try/catch. I tried `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty)`, but it still doesn't work. What is the solution here?

Comment: Do not use try when you should test listView1.SelectedItems.Count! This is a normal case.. Also do not pile so many commands into one line; hard to debug and in the way when adding checks..

Comment: The underlying problem is though, that I would like to make the user always select the row on which the item is on, regardless where he clicks, name or whitespace.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but my advice still applies! Which View mode do you use?

Comment: @EInherjar That's extremely easy, but you can't do it by writing a big blob of code in one go without thinking, and then staring helplessly at the screen when it doesn't do what you hoped it might. What you do instead is you use the properties of the listview to find out what the user clicked on. And then you have some ifs and so on to decide what to do with it. If it throws an index out of range exception, fix your code to check the index and only use the index when it's in range. If you get a null reference exception, fix your code so it doesn't do that. Check indexes, check for null.

Comment: You can try to turn on `FullRowSelect`. But you still should add the checks you are missing.. If this won't help you would have to do a `HitTest`, but imo that would not a propert solution, either..Why? Because the user __can't select__ the row by clicking truly emtpy space either. Therefore a doubleClick there __also should__ not work!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow always forget that. I am using the list View mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `ListView` is in `View=List` selecting makes it necessary to hit the item text.

This is inconvenient I have to admit and turnnig on `FullRowSelect` doesn't help, as it is only for `View=Details`.

Here is a quick fix:

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (hit.Item != null)
    {
        string file = hit.Item.Text;
        string[] arr1 = null;
        if (File.Exists(file)) arr1 = File.ReadLines(file).ToArray();
        ...
    }
}
```

You may instead want to go to the bottom of the issue and add code to the `MouseUp` event to **select** the row..:

```
private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (hit.Item != null) hit.Item.Selected = true;
}
```

Note that the `HitTest` will only catch `Items`, empty or not,  not really emtpy background space to the right or bottom..!